# Bootstrap navbar collapse not working correctly || navbar collapse not showing links on clicking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

***I am building navbar using bootstrap 5 in Angular 11***

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
 <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">O$hop</a>
 <button
  class="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
  aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault"
  aria-expanded="false"
  aria-label="Toggle navigation"
 >
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shopping-cart">Shopping Cart</a>
         </li>
          <ng-template #anonymousUser>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
         </li>
          </ng-template>

      <li
        ngbDropdown
        *ngIf="appUser; else anonymousUser"
        class="nav-item dropdown"
      >
      <a
      ngbDropdownToggle
      class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
      id="dropdown01"
      data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false"
      >{{ appUser.name }}</a
    >
    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
      <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/my/orders">My Orders</a>
      <ng-container *ngIf="appUser.isAdmin">
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/orders"
          >Manage Orders</a
        >
        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/products"
          >Manage Products</a
        ></ng-container
      >

      <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Log Out</a>
    </div>
   </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

**But on mobile screen, collpase button is not showing Shopping cart and dropdown toggle links..Any help ..I am new to Bootstrap....Attaching ss**..

[Fullscreen on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHXN7.png)

[When viewing on small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ6zr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the JS that is needed for bootstrap 5 for it to work.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can read more about it here:
[Bootstrap Introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: Thanks for help. But i got the issue, it needs a function defined in ts file  for toggle to work.

Comment: @jashandeepsingh What function?